# How to count workdays from git repository

Tags: git, bash

I want to know how many days I have been working on particular project (assuming that workday has at least one commit in this day).

So giving as input:

- repo
- username
- start date

I want to get

1. number of workdays between start date and today

or if possible

2. list of days with commits count, for instance:

   ```
   2016-05-05: 2 commits
   2016-05-07: 4 commits
   ...
   ```

Comment: Take a look at `git log` and `git shortlog`

Comment: @andlrc I need a script that will count and group by date hundreds of commits for me instead of looking at each commit and writing results on paper

Comment: what I ment what that you can parse the output of `git log` or `git shortlog` to archive your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a [quick hack like](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12099/number-of-commits-per-day-in-a-git-repository):

```
git log | grep Date | awk '{print " : "$4" "$3" "$6}' | uniq -c
```

With one less grep, suggested by [andlrc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180913/how-to-count-workdays-from-git-repository/37181633?noredirect=1#comment61896747_37181633):

```
git log | awk '/Date/ {print " : "$4" "$3" "$6}'| uniq -c
```

You can also try to apply **[gitstat](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/)** to your repo: it [includes number of commits (but mainly per month)](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/crossfire/activity.html).

You can combine that with [log between dates](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log/filtering-the-commit-history):

```
git log --after="2014-7-1" --before="2014-7-4"
```

---

The [OP ANTARA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768467/antara) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180913/how-to-count-workdays-from-git-repository/37181633?noredirect=1#comment61912476_37181633):

> it's almost perfect, but if the commit message contains "`Date`" keyword it breaks the counting, so I put small enhancement (pretty format):

```
 git log --pretty=format:"Date: %cd" --after 2015-11-23 | awk '/Date/ {print " : "$4" "$3" "$6}'| uniq -c
```

> To retrieve the workdays count (number of rows): `....... | wc -l`

Comment: Thanks, it's almost perfect, but if the commit message contains "Date" keyword it breaks the counting, so I put small enhancement (pretty format): git log --pretty=format:"Date: %cd" --after 2015-11-23 | awk '/Date/ {print " : "$4" "$3" "$6}'| uniq -c

Comment: @ANTARA Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.